# Probability to open a door using all the keys

Tags: probability

I have 1 door and 10 keys. What is the probablity to open the door trying all the keys? I will discard every single key time to time.

Comment: 1 if one of them is the right key, 0 otherwise.

Comment: Do you mean: What is the probability that the tenth key is the right one?

Comment: Maybe the question is: which is the probability that my last key is the correct one if I try every sigle key.

Comment: Yes, Austin. Thank you

Comment: For example, the probability to open the door with the 1st key I choose is 10%. Now, I need to know the probability to screw all the chances and open the door with the last key on my hand.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want the probability of unlocking the door on the $10$th try, if you discard keys whenever they fail, and assuming exactly one of the keys is correct. If so, just keep multiplying by the probability of getting a wrong key from those that remain, until finally you are down to one key. Notice a "collapsing" pattern as you go along?

Comment: 1/10 * 1/9 * 1/8 *.....1/1?

Comment: Not quite. The first will be $\frac9{10}$. The second will be $\frac89.$ You'll stop after $\frac12,$ since there will only be one key left, and it has to be right.

Comment: 7.07 % according with the mentioned arithmetic. Is this correct?

Comment: @John: That isn't right. Can you tell me the full list of the numbers you multiplied together?

Comment: Ok,please forget my last reply. Is this correct?: (9/10)(8/9)(7/8)(6/7)(5/6)(4/5)(3/4)(2/3)(1/2)

Comment: Yes. As you go through them from left to right, do you notice the pattern of products?

Comment: Yes, I think I got it know. Thank you for support on this ,Cameron!

Comment: No problem. You should make it a point to understand the other (at present) two answers, as well. You'll have an easier time of it if you can look at things from different perspectives and see how they mesh.

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that precisely one of the keys opens the door. We may want the probability that it is the $k$-th key that does it. Since all orderings of the keys are equally likely, the right key is just as likely to be in any position as in any other. So the probability we open the door on the $i$-th trial is $\dfrac{1}{10}$. That in particular applies to $i=10$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

**Hint:** How many permutations are there for the order of the 10 keys?

**Hint:** How many permutations are there, where the last key is the correct key?

---

Solution 2:

**Hint:** The probability that the last key is the correct key, is the same as the probability that the nth key is the correct key. Hence ...